# Есть тег, как вытащить из него данные? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 <LegalAddresses>
    <Address 
    PostCode="234113"
    Address="234133, МОСКВА ГОРОД, ПЕТРОВА, ДОМ 1А,КОРП III КОМН 34"
    REGION="МОСКВА ГОРОД"
    STREETNAME="ПЕТРОВА"
    BUILDINGNUMBER="ДОМ 1А"
    APART="КОРПIII КОМН 34"
    />
```

Есть вот такой тег. Нужно из него вытащить значения 
простым запросом не выходит

```
select  
    @xml.value('(Report/LegalAddresses/)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as id
```

Подскажите, как можно вытащить значения из самого тега?

Comment: что конкретно вы хотите видеть как результат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SELECT
      @xml
      = N'<LegalAddresses>
    <Address 
    PostCode="234113"
    Address="234133, МОСКВА ГОРОД, ПЕТРОВА, ДОМ 1А,КОРП III КОМН 34"
    REGION="МОСКВА ГОРОД"
    STREETNAME="ПЕТРОВА"
    BUILDINGNUMBER="ДОМ 1А"
    APART="КОРПIII КОМН 34"
    />
    </LegalAddresses>';

SELECT
      x.value('./@PostCode[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS PostCode,
      x.value('./@Address[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Address,
      x.value('./@REGION[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS REGION,
      x.value('./@STREETNAME[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS STREETNAME
INTO
      #MyXMLTable
FROM  @xml.nodes('LegalAddresses/Address') x(x);

SELECT
      PostCode,
      Address,
      REGION,
      STREETNAME
FROM  #MyXMLTable;
DROP TABLE #MyXMLTable;
```

Единственно что, я закрыл тег `<LegalAddresses>`

Comment: Т.е. для этого необходимо закрывать сам тег всегда?Мне бы логику понять)

Comment: Хотя я так понимаю Вы разбиваете всю строку с помощью nodes на отдельные данные и каждые данные эти вытаскиваете в нужный столбец

Comment: @Zeo если это целый XML тэг будет закрыт иначе ошибка. У вас я так понял кусочек.

Comment: Не, там был целый XML
нужно было вынуть именно данные из этого тега.
Ваше решение подошло, N не ставил в самой XML а в from просто прописал тег который выше
from  @xml.nodes('Report/LegalAddresses/Address') x(x);

Comment: @Zeo отлично, можете отметить его как верное. N'' служит для корректной обработки юникод значений.